# REST - Web Services is not default in Magento?

Tags: magento, rest

I can see the Soap / XMLRPC are default web services support by magento.
But REST is not default web services in Magento?

[Supported API Link](http://www.magentocommerce.com/api/soap/introduction.html)

But Magento Admin have the REST API Role Options in admin panel.

Comment: http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/doc/webservices-api/introduction_to_rest_api

Comment: http://inchoo.net/ecommerce/magento-rest-and-oauth-intro/

Comment: Very Thanks @ shivam.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

REST Web services is only added above `1.7.0 Version` in Magento.

Lower Magento versions are only support the `SOAP and XMLRPC` web services.

[Source Link](http://inchoo.net/ecommerce/magento-rest-and-oauth-intro/)